# Android Phonegap - In-app Purchases with Google Checkout

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase

Looking for a solution for in-app purchases since paypal is no longer an option for digital good purchases.
I'm not seeing any simple payment solution as you would think... I've checked out a plugin for phonegap: https://github.com/luoihoc/CallbackBillingPlugin

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why the down vote? :( this is a bad question??